# Структура БД новостного сайта с мультикатегориями и постраничной навигацией

Tags: архитектура, mysql

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Разрабатываю новостной сайт с категориями (без подкатегорий, но с возможность задать несколько категорий) и постраничной навигацией.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно спроектировать структуру базы данных, чтобы при больших объёмах данных всё работало быстро?

В новостной CMS DataLife Engine высмотрел один из вариантов: одна таблица с постами, где есть varchar поле с списком категорий через запятую, а выборка делается `WHERE category REGEXP '[[:<:]](25)[[:>:]]' LIMIT offset, count`, где 25 - id категории. Но на больших объёмах данных выборка будет происходить медленно (при 100к постов, запрос со смещением выполняется почти секунду).

СУБД: MySQL 5.6+

Благодарю.

С уважением.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Регекспами это конечно сурово.

Стандартно -

- таблица новостей (id, заголовок, контент  (обязательно для поля типа text гуглим barracuda mysql, либо вообще текст в виде файлов), id автора) ,
- таблица категорий id, название, описание(если надо),
- связывающая таблица ( id новости, id категории, primary key (id -новость,id категория))
- таблица авторов (id автора, имя, прочая инфа))

если у новости может быть не один автор, то вводим связывающую таблицу как для категорий.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. А запрос как выглядеть должен? Куча JOIN-ов?

Comment: @universal_mind, ну (пока) их максимум три, но вообще да. Таблицы авторов и категорий должны остаться относительно небольшими и запросы не превратятся в ультрамедленное. Опять же, в крайнем случае можно авторов, например, в кэше хранить поодиночке.

Answer (score 5):

> Разрабатываю новостной сайт с категориями (без подкатегорий, но с возможность задать несколько категорий) и постраничной навигацией.

безотносительно движка: будет таблица категорий, будет таблица новостей, будет промежуточная таблица связей многие ко многим.
[image]
Постраничная навигация обеспечивается стандартными средствами mysql (offset, limit). Если делать без извращений, то кроме pk дополнительных индексов не потребуется. В целом ситуация довольно тривиальная, тормоза будут только при хреновом движке и при хреновых запросах или когда количество новостей начнет исчисляться сотнями тысяч, я бы на этом этапе на такие цифры вообще не рассматривал. Если правильно организовать кэширование, то можно добиться того, что популярные материалы и главная будут браться не из базы данных, а прямо из оперативки.

```
 WHERE category REGEXP '[[:<:]](25)[[:>:]]' LIMIT offset, count
```

матерь божья.